# Image binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am having a little bit of trouble binding the back end to the front end image. The image is dynamic. Here is the code on the back end that serves the front end:

```
    public string currentCardImage
    {
        get
        {
            return currentCard.imageSource;
        }
    }
```

and the front end XAML for this is:

```
<Image Name="ImageMain"
       Source="{Binding currentCardImage}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Height="100"
       Margin="368,529,0,0"
       Grid.Row="1"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Width="100"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90.203" />
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Unfortunately this is not working. I can verify that there is data loaded into the currentCard and thus imageSource returns a location of the image.

Please let me know if you need more information. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The c# code is in the XAML code behind

Comment: Do you assign a DataContext to your View? Otherwise will the binding not work even when the code is in the CodeBehind file

Comment: did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Is your image Build Action set as Resource in the solution? When yes, try to use something like this: pack://application:,,,/Images/yourImage.png where Images is the folder where your image is located in the solution

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your binding fails is that Bindings are, by default, to the instance held within the `DataContext` property.  So, the binding

```
{Binding currentCardImage}
```

actually means

```
this.DataContext.currentCardImage
```

Since you say the property is in the *codebehind*, I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
public sealed class MyClass : Window
{
    public string currentCardImage
    {
        get { // SNIP!
```

In order to bind to this property, you have to *redirect* the binding to look to the root of the xaml tree (your Window) to start looking for the specified path.

The easiest way to do this is to name your root element

```
<Window x:Class="HerpDerp"
        HideOtherAttributesBecauseThisIsAnExample="true"
        x:Name="thisIsTheBindingTarget">
    <!-- snip -->
```

and tell your Binding to look there

```
{Binding currentCardImage, ElementName=thisIsTheBindingTarget}
```